# Stack overflow in my recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion, stack-overflow

Code is here , when i call numberOf 3 or numberOf integer>2 im getting this error  ERROR - C stack overflow . My code should change numbers between 2^(n-2) (2^n)-1 for n>2 to Binary and check if is there consecutive 0 or not . If is there dont count and if there isnt +1 .

```
numberOf :: Integer -> Integer  
numberOf i = worker i

worker :: Integer -> Integer  
worker i  
    | (abs i) == 0 = 0   
    | (abs i) == 1 = 2  
    | (abs i) == 2 = 3   
    | otherwise = calculat (2^((abs i)-2)) ((2^(abs i))-2)

calculat :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer  
calculat ab bis  
    | ab == bis && (checker(toBin ab)) == True = 1  
    | ab < bis && (checker(toBin ab)) == True = 1 + (calculat (ab+1) bis)  
    | otherwise =  0 + (calculat (ab+1) bis)  

checker :: [Integer] -> Bool  
checker list  
    | list == [] = True  
    | 0 == head list && (0 == head(tail list)) = False  
    | otherwise = checker ( tail list)  

toBin :: Integer -> [Integer]  
toBin n  
   | n ==0 = [0]  
   | n ==1 = [1]  
   | n `mod` 2 == 0 = toBin (n `div` 2) ++ [0]  
   | otherwise = toBin (n `div` 2) ++ [1]
```

Tests :

numberOf  3  Answer:(5)
numberOf  5         (13)
numberOf  10        (144)
numberOf  (-5)      (13)

Comment: (+1) for stack overflow in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies with your definition of `calculat`.  You have the cases of `ab == bis` and `ab < bis`, but the only place you call `calculat` is from `worker` with the arguments `2^(abs i - 1)` and `2^(abs i - 2)`.  Since the first number (`ab`) will always be larger than the second (`bis`), checking for `ab < bis` is pretty silly.  In your otherwise condition you then increment `ab`, ensuring that this function will never terminate.  Did you instead mean `otherwise = calculat ab (bis + 1)`?

---

You could also clean your code up substantially, there are many places where you've done things the hard way, or added unnecessary clutter:

```
-- Remove worker, having it separate from numberOf was pointless
numberOf :: Integer -> Integer
numberOf i
    | i' == 0 = 0
    | i' == 1 = 2
    | i' == 2 = 3
    -- Lots of unneeded parentheses
    | otherwise = calculat (2 ^ (i' - 1)) (2 ^ i' - 2)
    -- Avoid writing the same expression over and over again
    -- define a local name for `abs i`
    where i' = abs i

calculat :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
calculat ab bis
    -- Remove unneeded parens
    -- Don't need to compare a boolean to True, just use it already
    | ab == bis && checker (toBin ab) = 1
    | ab <  bis && checker (toBin ab) = 1 + calculat (ab + 1) bis
    -- 0 + something == something, don't perform unnecessary operations
    | otherwise                       = calculat (ab + 1) bis

-- Pattern matching in this function cleans it up a lot and prevents
-- errors from calling head on an empty list
checker :: [Integer] -> Bool
checker []      = True
checker (0:0:_) = False
checker (_:xs)  = checker xs

-- Again, pattern matching can clean things up, and I find an in-line
-- if statement to be more expressive than a guard.
toBin :: Integer -> [Integer]
toBin 0 = [0]
toBin 1 = [1]
toBin n = toBin (n `div` 2) ++ (if even n then [0] else [1])
```

Comment: i wanna check all numbers between 2^((abs i)-2) and (2^(abs i))-2 . this was my false . Sorry for that now i got this problem :               Program error: pattern match failure: head []

Comment: This is because you're calling `head (tail list)`, and `list` might only have one element.  In general, you should prefer pattern matching over using `head` and `tail`, I'll edit my post to show your code cleaned up.

Comment: Thank you very much , im just beginner at haskell and im not good yet. i dont know yet which code is unneeded or needed . Thank you again for your advices in code.

Comment: By test case numberOf 20 , it takes longer time and get C stack overflow error . Have you another advice for it ?

Comment: @Mert For `numberOf 20`, you're going to be checking every single number between `2^18` and `2^20-2`, or a total of 786430 numbers.  Your `toBin` and `checker` functions are not particularly efficient as lists aren't the right data structure to use here (`Data.Sequence.Seq` might be a better choice, `Data.Vector.Vector` would be the best).  You could also consider using `Data.Bits` and some fancy boolean logic to help, it's almost certainly faster than doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In calculat in case ab == bis but checker returns false you cant return from the function.

How about:

```
| ab >= bis && (checker(toBin ab)) == True = 1
| ab < bis && (checker(toBin ab)) == True = 1 + (calculat (ab+1) bis)  
| otherwise =  0 + (calculat (ab+1) bis)  
| ab >= bis = 0  
| ab < bis == True = 0 + (calculat (ab+1) bis)  
| otherwise =  0 + (calculat (ab+1) bis)
```

Comment: add ab== bis and checker false condition but still stack overflow

Comment: now i got: Program error: pattern match failure: head []  with this code     | ab >= bis && (checker(toBin ab)) == True = 1
   | ab < bis && (checker(toBin ab)) == True = 1 + (calculat(ab+1) bis)  
 | ab < bis = 0 + (calculat (ab+1) bis)  
 | otherwise =  0 + (calculat (ab+1) bis)